# How to make NavigationView's content fit to screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, prism

NavigationView: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview)

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <controls:TestView Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>

</Grid>
```

My TestView XAML(UserControl):

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> //StackPanel
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>    //Content/GridView
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> //StackPanel
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I noticed this behavior on navigationview, whenever the list contains many data or the height is too long, it will show all of the content , but I want the content to be fixed on the screen, can only scroll on the gridview.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the complete xaml content, I will edit base on your xaml.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I did post this answer, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue is on my navigationview control , I did put the frame inside ScrollViewer thats why the scrollviewer is always there lol.

Removed the ScrollViewer on my FRAME:

```
<Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" IsTabStop="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap all the content with [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) instead Grid, maybe it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, even inside the ScrollViewer, same results